# Custom setup for omnaith-auth0 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auth0

I am using omniauth-auth0 gem to have auth0 starategy in my app. Now I want to do custom setup, something like (for twitter):

```
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  user = User.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = user.consumer_key          # if using omniauth-oauth2
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = user.consumer_secret   # if using omniauth-oauth2
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = user.consumer_key       # if using omniauth-oauth
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = user.consumer_secret # if using omniauth-oauth
end

use OmniAuth::Builder.new do
  provider :twitter, :setup => SETUP_PROC
end
```

Unfortunately, for auth0 this is not working.How to do this in oomniauth-auth0 strategy?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to do this in omniauth-auth0 strategy?